# Change file permission in application

Tags: android, shell

I try to change file permission in application. Code is below:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /sdcard/test.txt");
```

This code NOT works in my application, but no error log.
I also checked the shell tools under /system/bin, find chmod is under /system/bin, but some other info shown that chmod > toolbox. I am not clear about this. My application has used android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system".
How to run this code or how to change permission of file? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your phone rooted? My guess is that such sensitive commands can't be used without being root.

Comment: I added Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") before, but it not works.

Answer (score 2):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc;
try {
    proc = rt.exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "chmod 777 " + Constants.filename });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e){ //DOSTUFFS }
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You've used the path `/sdcard/` in your test -- is your SD Card formatted with a filesystem that supports standard Unix permissions? ([FAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) does not.)

You did not give an explicit path to `chmod(1)` in your string -- are you certain that `chmod(1)` is:

- available on your device
- available with your current `PATH` environment variable setting?

You can only change the permissions on files you own; are you certain that whatever your application's effective userid is owns the file on the SD card?

Lastly, Android [may have additional security restrictions on changing file permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html). I don't know Android well, but perhaps changing file permission bits requires entries in the manifest declaring the operations, perhaps changing file permissions can only be done through provided APIs.

Comment: Run command as `$ su` `#chmod 777 /sdcard/test.txt`, permission can be changed. So i think the file path is right.

Comment: Try changing your string to `"su -c \"chmod 777 /sdcard/test.txt\""`