# Changing system file permission

Tags: android, permissions

I've really tried everything:

- [NetHackFileHelpers](https://nethack-android.googlecode.com/svn-history/r430/trunk/slashem-0.0.7E7F3/sys/android/NetHackApp/src/com/slashemff/NetHackFileHelpers.java)
- [How to get File Permission Mode programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408154/how-to-get-file-permission-mode-programmatically-in-java)
- [Change file permission in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412384/change-file-permission-in-application)
- [Mount R/W system in android application to edit Read Only files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129144/mount-r-w-system-in-android-application-to-edit-read-only-files)

Now, suppose I've remounted as root, and therefore `RW` permission on file system (Android version 2.3.7):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("chmod -c 0777 /system/etc/customization/settings/com/android/browser/custom_settings.xml\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
```

or:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"/system/etc/customization/settings/com/android/browser/custom_settings.xml\"");
```

or:

```
Class<?> fileUtils = Class.forName("android.os.FileUtils");
            Method setPermissions =
                fileUtils.getMethod("setPermissions", String.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);
            int a = (Integer) setPermissions.invoke(null, "/system/etc/customization/settings/com/android/browser/custom_settings.xml", 0777, -1, -1);
```

The behaviour is the same: nothing happens. Whereas if I `chmod` from adb shell works fine. How can I change the permissions of that file from within my code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
        Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, new File("/system/bin/"));
        OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();

        os.write(("chmod 777 <filepath>").getBytes("ASCII"));
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        sh.waitFor();
```

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/set-file-permissions-in-java-example/