# chmod 0777 /data/file is not working for rooted phone

Tags: android

I am using the current code and it will not work on a rooted phone.  Can anyone tell me why?

```
public void setpermission()
    {
    try
    { 
    Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    process1.waitFor();
    Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh chmod 0777  /data/playback.bin");
    process2.waitFor();
    }
    catch((Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could be encountering an issue when the command string is parsed.

`/system/bin/sh chmod 0777  /data/playback.bin` is treated as `"/system/bin/sh" "chmod" "0777"  "/data/playback.bin/"` with the extra quotes. Not sure if that is the reason for failure, but try the following instead:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream suStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

suStream.writeBytes("/system/bin/sh chmod 0777  /data/playback.bin" + "\n");

suStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
suStream.flush();
suStream.close();

process.waitFor();
```

Note that you should get the app root permission popup after `exec("su")`, so if you don't then it never gets to the point of even attempting to execute your file permission change command.

**EDIT** - You could also try this variation of the above (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13007584/808532)):

```
Process shell = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, new File("/system/bin/"));
OutputStream os = shell.getOutputStream();

os.write(("chmod 777 /data/playback.bin").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
shell.waitFor();
```

Comment: :Thanks for fast update, I used your code, Its asking permission(Grant or Deny) after executing Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); but after process.waitFor();its crashing, can you please guide me what might be the problem, in the mean time i will continue debugging.

Comment: See my edit. Also you should try opening a terminal directly and going superuser, then executing the chmod command yourself and see if there's any error output.

Comment: We need any SuperUser Apk installed on the Phone to get the above code to work (I Installed SuperSu via adb sideload) and this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all your  processes do start? I doubt there's a su though I might be wrong.

Comment: only process1 was starting after that process2 was throwing exeception & Exiting.